# Google Analytics: On Pageload Event?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm trying to add a Google Analytics Event to my site. The event should fire when a user registers and lands on a confirmation page.

Right now, I'm trying to load a pixel on the confirmation page and fire the event when the pixel loads. To do that, I tried adding this in the body of my confirmation page:

```
<img src="path-to-my-1x1.gif" onload="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Registration','Complete','Short Form']);">
```

Since GA now uses asynchronous tags, I noticed that I was getting a 'gaq is not defined' error (I'm assuming gaq.push was being called before the Analytics code loaded). To try and correct that, I added this directly below the Analytics code in my document head:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-111111']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

However, the event still isn't tracking. Do you know of a way I can configure this event to accomplish my goal?

Comment: Why do want to use the `img` `onload` handler? Simply track the event directly in a `script`.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to track a page load with an event? You can see the pages in the standard landing page reports. If you want to use it to trigger a goal you can also use the landing page it self. Normally I use events to track interactions with html elements.

Comment: @newllnhof -- I'm completely open to that, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: @NicoM -- It just makes it a little easier for me to work with -- With events, I can easily add parameters that let me know things like which page they entered the site, how many events were unique, etc. I can do those things with landing page reports or goal reports, but I prefer working with event reporting.